# Is it possible to disable the interlocutor's video in BlueJeans?

Tags: windows, bluejeans

Is it possible to disable all videos for anybody in the call in BlueJeans when in a videoconference?

The motivation is to reduce the network usage. I use BlueJeans on Microsoft Windows.

Interlocutor's video(s) = all videos for anybody in the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From BlueJeans' support:

> BlueJeans 2.18 (released 2020-01-03) introduces `Low Data Mode` for the desktop app which disables bi-directional video, cutting the required bandwidth down from Mbps to Kbps (in each direction). This helps your audio and screen share experience remain clear while on networks that may not be ideal for real time media. Mac has the ability to manually enable this. Windows is automatic during poor network conditions. In 2.19 Windows will get the ability to manually enable it as well.

[image]